# Map Caps key to Super+Alt+Ctrl?

Tags: bash, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I think it would be very useful to have my own `namespace` of shortcut keys where pretty much nothing would ever conflict. For example, I could assign <kbd>Caps</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to open Ask Ubuntu (or something similarly stupid) and that would really map to <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>. I've been trying to understand the custom keyboard settings, but that's one very confusing area of the OS.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! ;-) I'm sorry and, please, blame it on me: I'm confused and confusing...  But...  *What's your question???* :/

Comment: Sorry, that's not clear in the question. I want to remap CAPS to ctrl+alt+super. I feel there is a myriad of shortcut opportunities if this can be done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update** to remap <kbd>Caps</kbd> to <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>:

1. Open a terminal on type the following commands:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xautomation
   dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/xkb-options "['caps:none']"
   ```
2. Now create a small bash script that will use `xte` to create the keypress events. I added a `sleep 2` so that you can combine the tree keys with other ones (such as <kbd>a</kbd> or more).

   ```
   $ cat << EOF > /tmp/caps.sh
   #!/bin/bash

   xte 'keydown Control_L' 'keydown Super_L' 'keydown Alt_L'
   sleep 2
   xte 'keyup Control_L' 'keyup Super_L' 'keyup Alt_L'
   EOF
   ```

   Make it executable and move it to `/usr/local/bin`:

   ```
   chmod +x /tmp/caps.sh
   sudo mv /tmp/caps.sh /usr/local/bin
   ```
3. Finally create a custom shortcut from the System Settings menu as usual.

   [image]

   Since the <kbd>Caps</kbd> key has been disabled by the previous `dconf` command, you can just type it to define the shortcut accelerator. You'll see `0xff` as the key name but it will work.

---

Previous answer:

You don't need to define <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> as your internal shortcut since after all the key you want to use is <kbd>Caps</kbd>.

1. The first thing to do is to disable the default behaviour of this key, it can be done with the following command. Open a terminal an type:

   ```
   dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/xkb-options "['caps:none']"
   ```
2. Now define a custom keyboard shortcut using the System Settings Menu:

   [image]

   The command here can be as you suggested `xdg-open http://askubuntu.com`
3. The next step requires to go back to the command line as you can't type <kbd>Caps</kbd> to define a new combination accelerator. So list all the defined custom shorcuts with:

   ```
   $ dconf list /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/
   custom0/
   custom1/
   ```

   The one you've just created should be the last one, here `custom1`.
   Type the following command to assign <kbd>Caps</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> to open **[Askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com)**:

   ```
   dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom1/binding '<Caps>a'
   ```

   Adjust the `custom<id>` to match yours and the shortcut keys for your needs.

Your new <kbd>Caps</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> is ready to use, needless to log out or restart your system.

Comment: This is an awesome workaround, but it only works at the OS level.  My desire to use ctrl+alt+super is because it would work system wide in any app. -- Maybe it's just not possible?

Comment: @PKKid I've updated my answer to really remap caps to CTRL+SUPER+ALT

Comment: Sorry I was not around, how do I give you the extra +50 bounty on this?

Comment: @PKKid: don't worry. I'm glad that my update solved your problem.